# Is it possible to have non variable dimemsions in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I want to put an sql statement in a JTextArea. Right now I have this:

```
sql = new JTextArea(7, 20);
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(sql);
sql.setEditable(false);
sql.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
scrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

this.add(scrollPane1);
```

When I put the sql statement inside, the dimensions adjust to the content. In this case it makes the JTextArea as wide as the sql statement. What I want is that when it doesn't fit, it will split up and when this doesn't fit anymore, there will be a scrollpane. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for `JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord` and `JTextArea#setLineWrap` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JTextArea#setLineWrap(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29) by default is set to false.

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the text area. If set to true the
>   lines will be wrapped if they are too long to fit within the allocated
>   width. If set to false, the lines will always be unwrapped. A
>   PropertyChange event ("lineWrap") is fired when the policy is changed.
>   By default this property is false.

Also see this method [JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29)